# Drawing subgroup lattice of G in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-styles, tikz-trees

Since I am new to tikz I have made an attempt to draw the subgroup lattice in G, but struggling to make it work.
what I have tried

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
\title{Untergruppenverband der $A_4$}
\node(G)                            {$G$};
\node(81)       [below left of=G]  {$\langle\sigma^2,\tau\rangle$};
\node(82)       [below of=G]        {$\langle\sigma\rangle$};
\node(83)       [below right of=G]   {$\langle\sigma^2,\tau\sigma\rangle$};
\node(41)       [below left of=81] {$\langle\tau\sigma^2,\sigma^4\rangle$};
\node(42)       [below of=81]       {$\langle\tau,\sigma^4\rangle$};
\node(43)       [below of=82] {$\langle\sigma^2\rangle$};
\node(44)       [below of=83]       {$\langle\tau\sigma\rangle$};
\node(45)       [below right of=83]      {$\langle\tau\sigma^3$};
\node(21)       [below right of=41]     {$\langle\tau\sigma^6\rangle$}
\node(22)       [below of=41]       {$\langle\tau\sigma^2\rangle$}      
\node(23)       [below of=42]  {$\langle\tau\sigma^4\rangle$}
\node(24)       [below right of=42]   {$\tau$}
\node(25)       [below of=43]  {$\sigma^4$}
\node(1)        [below of=25]   {$1$}

\draw(G)       -- (81);
\draw(G)       -- (82);
\draw(G)       -- (83);
\draw(81)       -- (41);
\draw(81)       -- (42);
\draw(81)      -- (43);
\draw(82)      --  (43);
\draw(83)      --  (43);
\draw(83)      --  (44);
\draw(83)      --  (45);
\draw(41)      --  (21);
\draw(41)      --  (22);
\draw(41)       -- (25);
\draw(42)       -- (23);
\draw(42)       -- (24);
\draw(42)      -- (25);
\draw(21)      -- (1);
\draw(22)      --  (1);
\draw(23)      --  (1);
\draw(24)      --  (1);
\draw(24)      --  (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Lattice of subgroups of G}
\end{figure}
```

Where the nodes 81-83 correspond to the nodes from left to right below G, in a similar fashion 41 corresponds to the first below 81 from the left.
The desired result
[image]

Comment: In the future, when you post a question, always provide a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're pretty close. Use the `positioning` library. Then the correct syntax is `below=of G`, not `below of=G`. The node distance is measured along the diagonals, which is preventing the rows from lining up, so only position your nodes with `left`, `right` and `below`. This requires some reordering.

Lastly, you may want to use a single draw command, so that if you want to change the style of all the lines you only have to do it once, for example `\draw[thick]`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm]
\node(G)                {$G$};
\node(82)[below=of G]   {$\langle\sigma\rangle$};
\node(81)[left=of 82]   {$\langle\sigma^2,\tau\rangle$};
\node(83)[right=of 82]  {$\langle\sigma^2,\tau\sigma\rangle$};
\node(42)[below=of 81]  {$\langle\tau,\sigma^4\rangle$};
\node(41)[left=of 42]   {$\langle\tau\sigma^2,\sigma^4\rangle$};
\node(43)[below=of 82]  {$\langle\sigma^2\rangle$};
\node(44)[below=of 83]  {$\langle\tau\sigma\rangle$};
\node(45)[right=of 44]  {$\langle\tau\sigma^3\rangle$};
\node(25)[below=of 43]  {$\langle\sigma^4\rangle$};
\node(24)[left=of 25]   {$\langle\tau\rangle$};
\node(23)[left=of 24]   {$\langle\tau\sigma^4\rangle$};
\node(22)[left=of 23]   {$\langle\tau\sigma^2\rangle$}; 
\node(21)[left=of 22]   {$\langle\tau\sigma^6\rangle$};
\node(1)[below=of 25]   {$\{1\}$};

\draw(G)--(81)
    (G)--(82)
    (G)--(83)
    (81)--(41)
    (81)--(42)
    (81)--(43)
    (82)--(43)
    (83)--(43)
    (83)--(44)
    (83)--(45)
    (41)--(21)
    (41)--(22)
    (41)--(25)
    (42)--(23)
    (42)--(24)
    (42)--(25)
    (43)--(25)
    (21)--(1)
    (22)--(1)
    (23)--(1)
    (24)--(1)
    (24)--(1)
    (25)--(1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is great, I was thinking of making the lattice more compact like in my diagram, just so it takes less space in the latex document but this as good. Thank you!!! :)