# Make two nodes occupy the space of one node

Tags: spacing, tikz-cd, lattice

I would like to typeset a lattice like in the diagram below; on the left, two nodes appear to occupy the same horizontal spacing as the node above them, but can still have arrows drawn to and from them independently.

[image: Lattice with uneven spacing in penultimate row]

If I use dummy columns

```
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep = tiny]
    &&& &&& &G \\
    &&& &&\<\sigma^2, \tau\>& &\<\sigma\> &&\<\sigma^2, \tau\sigma\> \\
    &&\<**\>& &&\<\sigma^4, \tau\>& &\<\sigma^2\> &&\<**\>& &&\<**\> \\
    &\<\tau \sigma^2\>&&\<**\> &\<**\>&&\<\tau\> &\<\sigma^4\> \\
    &&& &&& &{\bf 1}
\end{tikzcd}
```

Then it's far too wide.
[image: Overly wide lattice]

Comment: Does [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/643290/125871) help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution with `\subnode` from the [`tikzmark` package/library](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikzmark). This will need the `remember picture` key and will write some lines to the `.aux` file. (There's a solution to do this without all this but with labels but `tikzmark` makes this pretty straight forward and easily adaptable for more than two subnodes.)

With the macro `\twoparts` one node is typeset but the `tikzmark` library creates pseudo nodes around both parts (named the same as the actual node but with suffix `-l` and `-r`). These names can be referenced later by using `from left`/`from right`/`to left`/`to right` without having to explicit give those nodes custom name (or figure out in which cell they actually are).

The parts are seperated by a space (note the `~`) but this can anything you want it to be. Maybe a `\quad` is better to distinguish both parts properly.

This all means we can still use the normal `\ar` target specification with `ldru` but only have to specify if we want the left or the right one of the source's or the target's cell.

To specify these arrows a bit easier I have defined a few keys:

- `to left`/`to right`,
- `from left`/`from right`,
- `to Left` is the same as `to left` but chooses the south anchor. Same for `to Right`. (I don't think it's necessary to the same when the edges coming from the top.) These are specific for this use-case since the angles are a bit unfortunate for these connections (and the source image does it too).

I've also defined `\ar` shortcuts since you always need edges to both subnodes.

- `\tolr` adds edges *to` both subnodes,
- `\toLR` adds edges *to* both subnodes but choose the `south` anchor at these subnodes.

Unrelated to the `\subnode` business but I've also added `\ldrar` to draw edges to both the left, middle and right “child” of the source cell.

I'm using the proper LaTeX macro `\mathbf` instead of `\bf` for the `1`.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{cd,tikzmark}
\def\<#1\>{\langle#1\rangle}% I guess …
\newcommand*{\twoparts}[3][]{%
  \subnode[#1]{\tikzmatrixname-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn-l}{#2}~%
  \subnode[#1]{\tikzmatrixname-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn-r}{#3}}
\makeatletter
\tikzcdset{
  from left/.style={from/.expanded=\tikzcd@ar@start-l},
  from right/.style={from/.expanded=\tikzcd@ar@start-r},
  to left/.style={to/.expanded=\tikzcd@ar@target-l},
  to right/.style={to/.expanded=\tikzcd@ar@target-r},
}
\makeatother
\tikzcdset{
  to Left/.style={to left, end anchor=south},
  to Right/.style={to right, end anchor=south},
  install my shortcuts/.code={%
    \newcommand*\ldrar{\dlar\dar\drar}%
    \newcommand*\tolr[1][]{\ar[##1,to left]\ar[##1,to right]}%
    \newcommand*\toLR[1][]{\ar[##1,to Left]\ar[##1,to Right]}%
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[
  remember picture,
  column sep = tiny,
  arrows=-, crossing over clearance=3pt,
  install my shortcuts]
  & & G \ldrar \\
  & \<\sigma^2, \tau\> \ldrar 
    & \<\sigma\>  \dar
      & \<\sigma^2, \tau\sigma\> \ldrar  \\
\<**\> \tolr[d]
  & \<\sigma^4, \tau\> \tolr[d]\drar
    & \<**\> \dar
      & \<**\>  \dlar
        & \<**\> \ar[dll] \\
\twoparts{\<\tau \sigma^2\>}{\<**\>}
  & \twoparts{\<**\>}{\<\tau\>}
    & \<\sigma^4\> \dar  \ar[ull, crossing over] \\
  & & \mathbf{1} \toLR[ul]\toLR[ull]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: I actually have `\newcommand{\<}{\left<}` and likewise for right, not that it really matters. Thank you!